# Not able to install composer-cli on MAC

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to install composer cli on my mac. npm says install was good:

```
Peeyushs-MacBook-Pro:fabric-dev-servers peeyush$ npm install -g composer-cli@0.20 --python=python2.7
/usr/local/bin/composer -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/cli.js
/usr/local/lib
└── composer-cli@0.20.0
```

But when I try to run it, I get command not found:

```
Peeyushs-MacBook-Pro:fabric-dev-servers peeyush$ composer-cli
-bash: composer-cli: command not found
```

I am following this guide: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools.html

Can you please help me figure out what is the issue here? TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you want is `composer` not `composer-cli`. But you could still have problems. You have installed node into /usr (ie you installed it as root) and this can also lead to problems.
In our documentation we highly recommend you don't do this but install node as your local user. We recommend using `nvm` for this. I highly suggest you follow our documentation to avoid hitting further issues. You should uninstall node first, then restart using `nvm` is the recommendation.

Comment: Thank you! Removing the node and reinstalling worked.

Answer (score 0):

The following capture is the documentation that is given on the site
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools.html which explicitly says to use the command composer-cli and this is what gives me the error:
code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! grpc@1.10.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.10.1 install script.

As you said, when I use the command composer, 3 packages are added from 4 contributors 
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FI1iA.png)